# Module that rotates each cell of a 3x3 array around the central cell (not a matrix rotation)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to rotate an array but not like a basic matrix rotation. If I have a 3x3 array, I want each of the cells to turn around the central cell.

Here is a 3x3 array:

```
import numpy as np

tab = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

I want for instance to rotate it by 45 degrees:

```
[[2 3 6]
 [1 5 9]
 [4 7 8]]
```

I can't use `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(tab,45)` because it applies a basic matrix rotation and this is not what I want.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

tab = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

ndimage.interpolation.rotate(tab,45)

[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 2 6 0]
 [0 4 8 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

Does anybody know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your almost had it just use this:

```
ndimage.interpolation.rotate(tab,45,reshape=False,mode='nearest')
```

the thing is you need to force the method to not reshape your matrix and also use nearest number as fill in the blank instead of zeros.

The problem with zeros is that some numbers (the ones in the corners) become out of boundaries when you rotate the matrix so you need to "predict" those missing corners by nearest like precised [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html)

output:

```
[[2 3 6]
 [1 5 9]
 [4 7 8]]
```

rotate it again it gives:

```
[[3 6 9]
 [2 5 8]
 [1 4 7]]
```

etc..

Comment: This probably won't do the right thing for  matrices larger than 3x3

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to use it on 3x3 arrays, a simple solution would be to list the indexes in a clockwise/anticlockwise order (eg: `[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0), (1, 0)]`), then for the rotations you just shift the values according to the list indexes (by degrees/45° places).

Comment: I accepted @Rayhane Mama answer because it is what I wanted but your answer still works, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a pair of index arrays (in which a rotation can be seen visually):

```
i = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 2]
])
j = np.array([
    [1, 2, 2],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 0, 1]
])
```

Which then works as desired:

```
>>> tab = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> tab[i,j]
array([[2, 3, 6],
       [1, 5, 9],
       [4, 7, 8]])
```

This is essentially a vectorized implementation of Balázs Kovacsics' solution, which should be faster than the `ndimage` solution

To rotate twice, you can use either

```
>>> tab[i,j][i,j]
array([[3, 6, 9],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [1, 4, 7]])

>>> i2 = i[i,j]
>>> j2 = j[i,j]
>>> tab[i2,j2]
array([[3, 6, 9],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [1, 4, 7]])
```